# IE7 doesn't call javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently building a website using ASP.Net MVC 1 and using [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) javascript file in order to replace the default radio buttons with images. I'm using the radio buttons to toggle between two forms using jQuery .toggle.

This works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE8, but doesn't work at all in IE7.  However, if I inspect the code using IE's developer tools and add a space into the onclick method at runtime, it works.

I have no idea why this is, I've tried various combinations of jQuery, regular javascript, using return false; and many variations thereupon to no avail.

If anyone could shed any light, it would be much appreciated.  Relevent code below.

Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;

    for (a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if (inputs[a].type == "radio" && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");

            span[a].className = inputs[a].type;
            span[a].setAttribute("onclick", inputs[a].getAttributeNode("onclick").nodeValue);
            if (inputs[a].checked == true) {
                position = "0 -" + (radioHeight * 2) + "px";
                span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
            }
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
            if (!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
            } else {
                span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("rbCustomerSelect", true,Model.IsNewCustomer.GetValueOrDefault(false),new { id="NewCustomerRadioButton", @class="styled", onclick="ShowNewCustomerForm(true);" })%>
```

Which is rendered as:

```
<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -50px;" onclick="ShowNewCustomerForm(true);"/>
```

Comment: Is there a javascript error thrown when you click on the radio before adding a space?  Perhaps at interpretation time?  The next obvious question is, why not just have the server return spans instead of inputs?

Comment: No javascript errors at all.  At least none that are caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you were using jQuery, so I recommend binding to the click event when the DOM has loaded and the span tag has been generated from the radiobutton. The beauty of jQuery is that it tries to maintain a level of conformity across different javascript implementations.

Try getting rid of the onclick parameter, and altering the javascript so that it gives the generated spans an id.
Add the following line:

```
span[a].className = inputs[a].type;
span[a].id = inputs[a].id + "-span";
```

Then use this javascript to bind to the click event after the span is generated

```
$(function(){
   $("#NewCustomerRadioButton-span").click(function(){ShowNewCustomerForm(true)});
})
```

Perhaps IE7 isn't properly registering the span as a DOM element, but using jQuery to bind to the click event should fix this.

Comment: In your example, you'd be trying to assign the result of `ShowNewCustomerForm(true)` as a click handler -- not the function itself. Wrap it: `.click( function(){ ShowNewCustomerForm(true); } )` or assign it as a function reference: `.click( ShowNewCustomerForm )`.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I am interested to find out why @Steve is using the onclick event - where clearly he has a good handle on jQuery functionality.  I prefer to use onclicks where possible as it helps maintainability a bunch (knowing which click methods are attached to which elements.

Comment: I'm using the onclick event because when I tried to bind to the click event, the function would fire on page load without the button being clicked.  Also, @Ken, that didn't work.

Comment: That code should be put into the $(document).ready(function() { ... }

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { ... })  === $(function(){ ... })

Comment: I had that code in the $(document).ready section to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, missed your edited answer. What I found was that the document.ready was being called before the external js file which meant the click handler was being assigned to an element that didn't exist yet.  To make it work, I called the external function manually at the start of document.ready, added in your section and it works in all browsers now.